# sending mail: gmail recipient will get an event in calendar

Tags: email, gmail, google-calendar-api

I have an application which sends emails to sport competitors concerning competition event (place, date,...).
Sometimes, one of them (teenagers) just forgets to come to the competition.

They all have smartphones, but instead of sending a SMS reminder to be sure they will all be presents, I am wondering if it is possible that the email for gmail address recipient generates (auto or ask) an event in google calendar. Something similar to book confirmation emails from hotels or travels.

I have tested some mails with a date+hour in the subject, or something like this in the body:

```
Start: 19/07/2016 16:35
End: 19/07/2016 17:30
```

But gmail did not proposes anything, and nothing happen in my calendar. (auto add option in calendar is enabled).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an ICS file as an attachment with your email . See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar for more information

Comment: It fits exactly what I am looking for !
Thanks